# Window handle of listview becomes unusable after subclassing

Tags: c, winapi

In one of my c winapi applications I have the following lines:

```
(1) ListView_SetImageList(hwnd_listview, himagelist, LVSIL_SMALL);

(2) SetWindowLong(hwnd_listview, GWL_WNDPROC, (LPARAM) ListViewWndproc);

(3) ListView_GetBkColor(hwnd_listview);
```

After command 2 (SetWindowLong) - subclassing - the handle (hwnd_listview) becomes unusable. The application crashes with command 3.

(The application runs on Windows Server 2003.)

Is this normal?

What can I do to retain the handle?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Edit:

Thanks for the link - IInspectable - I cannot use the new method since my application is ansi.

@JosephH: The ListViewWndproc is pretty long. Why should it be relevant in this case?

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ListViewWndproc (HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)   
{
  switch (msg) {
    case WM_CREATE:
      ...
      break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
      switch (wParam) {
        case 0x4E: 
          ...
          break;
      }
      break;
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
      ...
      break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
      ...
      break;
    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
      ...
      break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
      ...
      break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
      if (HIWORD (wParam) == CBN_SELCHANGE) {
        ...
      }
      else if (HIWORD (wParam) == CBN_SELENDCANCEL) {
        ...
      }
      else {
        ...
        }
      }
      break;
    case WM_NOTIFY:
      lpNmHdr = (LPNMHDR) lParam;
      if (lpNmHdr->code == MCN_SELECT) {
        ...
      }
      break;
  }
  return CallWindowProc(self->OldListViewWndproc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Dr. Watson Log says:
Exception number: c0000005 (access violation)

When I log each call to the new windows procedure I get one entry with the 
msg number 4127!??

Now I see the problem:

In the window procedure of my main application window I need a certain pointer (self). I get this value by this:

```
case WM_CREATE:
      cs   = (CREATESTRUCT*) lParam;
      self =  cs->lpCreateParams;      
  break;
```

In the window procedure of the subclassed listview I also need this pointer. So I just "copied" the lines and forgot that in the case of the listview I subclass an existing listview so this code (WM_CREATE) never gets executed.

But what is - in this case the best way to get the pointer into the window procedure of the listview?

I searched and found it: I need global subclassing.

In step 1 I create a hidden listview in order to get a listview handle.

Then I call the following to do global subclassing:

```
self->OldListViewWndproc = (WNDPROC) SetClassLong(hwnd_listview, GCL_WNDPROC, (LONG) ListViewWndproc);
```

Now I can create the "real" listview widget and I can pass the "self" value to the window procedure in the same way as with the main window.

Comment: You need to paste the code for ListViewWndproc; otherwise, it's impossible tell what you're doing with the subclassed list view.

Comment: You should consider properly [subclassing controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx).

Comment: The ListViewWndproc is not only relevant, it is central to the problem. You said "When somebody tries to send a message to the listview, use my function instead of the regular one." So your function is the one that is not working. If it's too long, then you should remove code from it until it is the smallest possible code that still demonstrates the problem. For example, you could start with a subclass that does nothing.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: Your comment helped me to see this relation. Now I can do the next step to inspect my new Window Procedure. If you put this as answer than I will vote for it.

Comment: The new method is not exclusive to Unicode programs. Are you stuck on Common Controls 5? Also what kind of crash do you have? What does the debugger say when the program crashes?

Comment: What is `self`? How is `self->OldListViewWndproc` initialized? Why not set a breakpoint on your `ListViewWndproc` and step through it? Or why not look at the stack trace in the debugger when the exception occurs?

Comment: The new Common Controls 6 subclassing system would allow you to give the `self` pointer to your subclass procedure without global subclassing or other weird tricks. Keep this in mind for any future developments.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: We still have the old "cl.exe" from Visual Studio 6 and use it with Notdepad++. We do not use the old VS 6 IDE with the debugger. Why not? I do not know. The decision was made before I joined the team.

Comment: The .pdb file format (used to enable source debugging) is compatible with any Windows debugger. If you don't feel like using the IDE, you can use one of the debuggers that are part of the [Debugging Tools for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063.aspx) (WinDbg, KD, CBD).